# jQuery - Targeting a checkbox with a value containing double quotes

Tags: javascript, html-entities

I am attempting to pre-populate a form which has inputs with values I am not able to change. One of the fields is a series of checkboxes and some of the values contain double quotes to represnt inches. I have an array of values I want to change to checked but I'm not sure how to target those inputs with values containing double quotes.

```js
let sizeArr = ['short', 'under 28"', 'over 28"'];
sizeArr.forEach(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
    $(':checkbox[value='+ val +']').prop('checked', 'true');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  Short
  <input type="checkbox" value="short" />
</label>

<label>
  Under 28"
  <input type="checkbox" value="under 28&quot;">
</label>

<label>
  Over 28"
  <input type="checkbox" value="over 28&quot;">
</label>
```

I also tried replacing the double quotes with `&quot;` directly in the array, but the selector still doesn't seem to work:

```js
let sizeArr = ['short', 'under 28&quot;', 'over 28&quot;'];
sizeArr.forEach(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
    $(':checkbox[value='+ val +']').prop('checked', 'true');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  Short
  <input type="checkbox" value="short" />
</label>

<label>
  Under 28"
  <input type="checkbox" value="under 28&quot;">
</label>

<label>
  Over 28"
  <input type="checkbox" value="over 28&quot;">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly concatenate the value into the selector string you can use the filter function to manually match the element's value against the desired value.

```
sizeArr.forEach(function(val) {
    $(':checkbox').filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() === val;
    }).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `CSS.escape()`:

```js
let sizeArr = ['short', 'under 28"', 'over 28"'];
sizeArr.forEach(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
    $(':checkbox[value='+ CSS.escape(val) +']').prop('checked', 'true');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  Short
  <input type="checkbox" value="short" />
</label>

<label>
  Under 28"
  <input type="checkbox" value="under 28&quot;">
</label>

<label>
  Over 28"
  <input type="checkbox" value="over 28&quot;">
</label>
```